# doNothing.When for private void method itself is invoking method

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

I'm trying to test one of my Class named Store and particularly a method named removeFromFavourite
below is the method

```
    public void removeFromFavourite(Quote quote) {
        if(quote == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Quote can't be null");
        }
        if (quote.getId() <1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Quote id can't be less than 1");
        }
        realm.beginTransaction();
        QuoteRealMObject object = realm.where(QuoteRealMObject.class).
                equalTo(QuoteRealMObject.ID, quote.getId()).findFirst();
        if(object != null) {
            deleteObject(object);
        }
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }


    private void deleteObject(RealmObject object) {
        object.deleteFromRealm();
    }
```

I created deleteObject method to call deleteFromRealm as deleteFromRealm is final and hence i can't mock it.

My expectation is to mock call to 'deleteObject' ob Store's object by creating its spy

Here's my `@Before` method

```
private Realm mockedRealm;
private Store store;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mockedRealm = Mockito.mock(Realm.class);
    store = new Store(mockedRealm);
    store = PowerMockito.spy(store);
}
```

So i created a mock object of Realm and used this to create object of class Store and then created a spy out of store's object and assigned it back to store object itself.

Below is test method for removeFromFavourite

```
@Test
    public void removeFromFavourite() throws Exception {
        Quote quot = new Quote();
        quot.setId(1);
        RealmQuery<QuoteRealMObject> query = Mockito.mock(RealmQuery.class);
        RealmQuery<QuoteRealMObject> filteredQuery = Mockito.mock(RealmQuery.class);
        Mockito.when(mockedRealm.where(QuoteRealMObject.class)).thenReturn(query);
        Mockito.when(query.equalTo(QuoteRealMObject.ID, 1)).thenReturn(filteredQuery);
        QuoteRealMObject mockedObject = Mockito.mock(QuoteRealMObject.class);
        Mockito.when(filteredQuery.findFirst()).thenReturn(mockedObject);
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(store, "deleteObject", mockedObject);            
        store.removeFromFavourite(quot);
    }
```

Here's line `PowerMockito.doNothing().when(store, "deleteObject", mockedObject);` itself is calling real private method "deleteObject"
and I am getting unfinished Mocking exception

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at com.kgcorner.vachan.io.StoreTest.removeFromFavourite(StoreTest.java:132)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed


    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$1.testFinished(DefaultInternalRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.SynchronizedRunListener.testFinished(SynchronizedRunListener.java:56)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$7.notifyListener(RunNotifier.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$SafeNotifier.run(RunNotifier.java:72)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.fireTestFinished(RunNotifier.java:187)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.EachTestNotifier.fireTestFinished(EachTestNotifier.java:38)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:79)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:85)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Any idea, where I am mistaking?

Answer (score 1):

I think the third argument in the `when` should be a mockito matcher:

```java
PowerMockito.doNothing().when(store, "deleteObject", eq(mockedObject));
```

Answer (score 1):

Mockito provides a method **doNothing()** to mock the calls for void method. For the question above void method **deleteFromRealm** can be mocked like

```
Mockito.doNothing().when(mockedObject).deleteFromRealm();
```

As **deleteFromRealm** is final and can not be mocked. To mock method **deleteObject** of same class

```
ClassToBeTested testClass = new ClassToBeTested();
ClassToBeTested testClassSpy = PowerMockito.spy(testClass);
PowerMockito.doNothing().when(testClassSpy, "deleteObject", mockedRealm);
```

Comment: Hey there! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I have called deleteFromRealm from another private method because deleteFromRealm is final and can't be mocked. Hence I am looking to mock call to private method deleteObject

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little bit too late, but a possible solution for your problem might look something like this:

```
PowerMockito.doNothing().when(store, "deleteObject", Matchers.any(RealmObject.class));
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You need add your mock class in `PrepareForTest` annotation at test class to actually prepare powermockito to mock private methods

```
public class A{

private void deleteObject(RealmObject object) {
        object.deleteFromRealm();
    }
}
```

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(A.class)
public class ATest{

@Spy
A mock;

@Test
public void test(){
   PowerMockito.doNothing().when(mock,  method(TaskReqImpl.class,"deleteObject", RealmObject .class)); 
   // OR
   PowerMockito.doNothing().when(mock, "deleteObject", any());     
}
```